# Need to concat these two results

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to concatetnate the string returned by the below SQL statements.

```
 select substr(IB_TGTLOCATION,INSTR(IB_TGTLOCATION,'/',1,3)+1) from PSIBSVCSETUP;
```

and

```
 select substr(connurl,1,INSTR(connurl,'/',1,3)) from PSGATEWAY where LOCAL_FLAG='Y';
```

and update this table with the concatenated result of the above two select statements, instead of the UPDATEDSTRING text.

```
Update PSIBSVCSETUP SET IB_TGTLOCATION=('UPDATEDSTRING') where SEQNO=1;
```

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: Are there only one row in each of these two tables? If not, how should the match between rows in PSIBSVCSETUP and PSGATEWAY be made?

Comment: yes there is only one row in the first table.In the second table there are two rows but the where clause  makes sure that we get only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both query returns one row

```
Update PSIBSVCSETUP SET IB_TGTLOCATION=(
 (select substr(IB_TGTLOCATION,INSTR(IB_TGTLOCATION,'/',1,3)+1) from PSIBSVCSETUP) || 
 (select substr(connurl,1,INSTR(connurl,'/',1,3)) from PSGATEWAY where LOCAL_FLAG='Y')
) where SEQNO=1;
```

else you have to join tables.